# UIBarButtonItem disability not displayed

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ios9, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` which should be enabled according to the input of a text field. So every time the text field is empty (I make use of the `UITextFieldDelegate`), the button is disabled, otherwise enabled. Though it is **acting** enabled/disabled it doesn't actually represent its state **visually**. That means if it has been enabled and gets disabled it's still looking enabled but not selectable and the other way around. What could be the problem and how could I get rid of this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `UIBarButtonItem` as an Outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var DoneButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Then you can disable/ enable it like this:

```
DoneButton.enabled = false
```

And make it look disable like this:

```
DoneButton.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable/disable it from its superView if you wan't to change the tint and disable it at the same time, as such:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
// If  the button is the left button in a navBar
```